# Data from file when variable number of data

Tags: datatool, csv

I am using the datatool package in order to get data from a csv to LaTeX pdf pages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}
\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{data}{students.csv}

\DTLforeach{data}
{\student=Name,\pointsa=Pointsa,\pointsb=Pointsb}
{\newpage 
   Student: \student\\
   Points exercise A: \pointsa\\
   Points exercise B: \pointsb
}
\end{document}
```

Since I don't always have the same number of exercises I would like to have a template that can automatically adapt to the number of exercises based on the csv only (based on the number of points in that csv).

In a regular programming language I would make "points" an array and loop through the arrow to create the points for all exercises.

How can I achieve this functionality (variable number of exercises but one fixed template)? I can see two solutions but don't know how to implement them, or whether it is possible at all:

- have an array with points in the csv (Is this even possible?)
- have all the points at the end of the lines in the csv and get points until EOL

I would appreciate any hints in how to tackle this. If necessary I could also use another package.

Comment: If you're familiar with other programming languages you might want to consider using these to *generate* TeX source code, or something like PythonTeX. You might find it easier to maintain or understand the code.

Comment: If you know Linux, should take a look to AMC (auto multiple choice), It is a LaTeX  package but much more than that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your data looks like and I am not even sure that I understood correctly what you want to achieve, but maybe you can just start with something simple like this (this solution does not allow for arbitrary numbers of columns, however):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{filecontents}[noheader]{students.csv}
Name,      PointsA, PointsB, PointsC, PointsD
Student A, 10,      11,      12,      13
Student B,   ,      15,        ,      17
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\DTLloaddb{data}{students.csv}

\DTLforeach{data}
{\student=Name,\pointsa=PointsA,\pointsb=PointsB,\pointsc=PointsC,\pointsd=PointsD}
{
    \begin{tabular}{ll} 
        Student: & \student \\
        \ifx\pointsa\empty\else Points exercise A: & \pointsa \\ \fi
        \ifx\pointsb\empty\else Points exercise B: & \pointsb \\ \fi
        \ifx\pointsc\empty\else Points exercise C: & \pointsc \\ \fi
        \ifx\pointsd\empty\else Points exercise D: & \pointsd \\ \fi
    \end{tabular}
    
    \bigskip
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

After a second read of your question, I assume that your data is stored in one or many CSV files where the first column is some kind of identifier (the students' names) and the rest can be any number of columns that contain integer values (or something similar).

Hence, I came up with this alternative approach which makes use of the `pgfplotstable` package. This solution accepts CSV files with an arbitrary number of columns. The first should contain the student's name, the following columns should contain the points for the various exams. This solution automatically sets the names for the exams as A, B, C etc.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}{studentsA.csv}
Name,      PointsA, PointsB, PointsC, PointsD
Student A, 10,      11,      12,      13
Student B,   ,      15,        ,      17
\end{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{studentsB.csv}
Name,      PointsA, PointsB, PointsC, PointsD, PointsE, PointsF
Student C, 10,      11,      12,      13,      14,      
Student D,   ,      15,        ,      17,      18,      19
\end{filecontents}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_studentstable_datarows_tl
\tl_new:N \l_studentstable_datacols_tl
\str_new:N \l_studentstable_currentstudent_str
\str_new:N \l_studentstable_tempexercise_str
\tl_new:N \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \printStudentsTable } { m } {
    \pgfplotstableread[col~sep=comma]{#1}{\studentsdata}

    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\studentsdata}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l_studentstable_datarows_tl}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\studentsdata}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l_studentstable_datacols_tl}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

    \foreach \i in {0,...,\l_studentstable_datarows_tl} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\studentsdata}
        \str_set:Nx \l_studentstable_currentstudent_str { \pgfplotsretval }

        \str_clear:N \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\l_studentstable_datacols_tl} {
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]\j}\of{\studentsdata}
            \str_set:Nx \l_studentstable_tempexercise_str {
                \str_uppercase:f { \int_to_alph:n { \j } }
            }
            \tl_gput_right:Nx \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl { 
                \str_if_empty:NTF \pgfplotsretval { } {
                    Points~exercise~\l_studentstable_tempexercise_str \c_colon_str &
                    \pgfplotsretval \\
                }

            }
        }

        \begin{tabular}{ l l } 
            Student: & \l_studentstable_currentstudent_str \\
            \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl
        \end{tabular}
        \par
        \bigskip
        \par
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printStudentsTable{studentsA.csv}

\printStudentsTable{studentsB.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to print the descriptions of the exams, you can adjust the code as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{filecontents}{studentsC.csv}
Name,      Exam A, Exam B, Test C
Student C, 10,     11,     12 
Student D,   ,     15,       
\end{filecontents}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_studentstable_datarows_tl
\tl_new:N \l_studentstable_datacols_tl
\str_new:N \l_studentstable_currentstudent_str
\str_new:N \l_studentstable_tempexercise_str
\tl_new:N \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \printStudentsTable } { m } {
    \pgfplotstableread[col~sep=comma]{#1}{\studentsdata}

    \pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\studentsdata}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l_studentstable_datarows_tl}{\pgfplotsretval-1}
    
    \pgfplotstablegetcolsof{\studentsdata}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\l_studentstable_datacols_tl}{\pgfplotsretval-1}

    \foreach \i in {0,...,\l_studentstable_datarows_tl} {
        \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]0}\of{\studentsdata}
        \str_set:Nx \l_studentstable_currentstudent_str { \pgfplotsretval }

        \str_clear:N \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl
        \foreach \j in {1,...,\l_studentstable_datacols_tl} {
            \pgfplotstablegetcolumnnamebyindex{\j}\of{\studentsdata}
                \to\pgfplotsretval
            \str_set:Nx \l_studentstable_tempexercise_str {
                \pgfplotsretval
            }
            \pgfplotstablegetelem{\i}{[index]\j}\of{\studentsdata}
            \tl_gput_right:Nx \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl { 
                \str_if_empty:NTF \pgfplotsretval { } {
                    Points~\l_studentstable_tempexercise_str \c_colon_str &
                    \pgfplotsretval \\
                }

            }
        }

        \begin{tabular}{ l l } 
            Student: & \l_studentstable_currentstudent_str \\
            \l_studentstable_currentpointslist_tl
        \end{tabular}
        \par
        \bigskip
        \par
    }
}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\printStudentsTable{studentsC.csv}

\end{document}
```

[image]